# What is a Killswitch?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, artificer, warlord

I know it's a Warlord|Artificer Hybrid, but when I try to look it up, I just get broken links. What does it do and how do I build one?

Answer (score 8):

[Killswitch](https://web.archive.org/web/20151027192111/http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2676866) from the old WotC boards via the Wayback Machine

The basic idea of the build given is that thread is:

> -- Create Instant Advantage, and decide the outcome of the encounter on T1. This becomes possible in very early Paragon, with the arrival of the 'Combat Commander' and 'Enhanced Resistive Formula' feats, and the 'Spell Commander' Paragon Path.
>
> -- Be truly 'optimal' from Level 1 through Level 30.

It does this by having many abilities that help a party by doing things like granting free movement and attacks, and giving bonuses to the attack and damage rolls of allies while also being a decent healer.

Comment: Might be worth noting that there were a few "switches", of which Killswitch was one.  The others are Flameswitch (Shaman|Warlord), Chordswitch (Bard|Ardent), Lightwitch (Artificer|Cleric) and Thoughtswitch/Mindswitch (Psion|Warlord).  Lightswitch, Flameswitch, and Chordswitch are all available at enworld (links under Leaders http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?472893-4E-Character-Optimization-WOTC-rescue-Handbook-Guide ), and Thoughtswitch/Mindswitch, which were never fully built out, at https://web.archive.org/web/20150916164841/http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3464226